# Difference between GCC's GNU C standards and ANSI C?

Tags: c, gcc

Can anybody describe the differences between the GNU C standards of GCC, and ANSI C?
Which is better and why?

Answer (score 3):

Relevant part of the GCC documentation: http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.7.2/gcc/C-Extensions.html

About knowing which is better, you need to specify the purpose...

Comment: +1 for "About knowing which is better, you need to specify the purpose..."  Agreed, a question that includes the word *better* needs to come with a *for ...* clause.

Comment: +1 for the veiled RT?M - GCC actually does a reasonable job (not the best I've seen, but far from the worst) documenting what it does that differs from the standards.

Comment: @JeremyJStarcher actually no, if you don't know differences between them, it's still useful to seek the pro's and con's. you could have many different purposes.

Answer (score 3):

GNU C is a C compiler....  ANSI C is a standard.

various compilers can compile ANSI C, but also often have their own extensions

Comment: To add to this the ANSI C standard has a lot of "implementation defined" items, meaning two compilers can both meet the spec but differ in how they implement some of these items.  Gnu C implements these items in one way that maybe different from other compilers.

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking GNU C is an extension of whatever ANSI GNU fully supports. It will sometimes include future/beta/proposed standards. Almost always, GNU C will support whatever the highest ANSI C they support does. The only down side of using GNU C is that if you write for GNU C that your code will be less portable.